# Python convert string to date in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I kindly ask you to help me with the following

I have a dataframe of string that I would like to convert to dates. Unfortunately, system generates an error

```
Dataframe 
  ID                    col_1
0  1  \/Date(1529424891295)\/
1  2  \/Date(1529424891295)\/
2  3  \/Date(1529424891295)\/

def convert_dates(timestamp_str):
    timestamp2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp_str[7:20])/1000)
    timestamp3 = timestamp2.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    return timestamp3

df['col_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: convert_dates('col_1'), axis=1)
```

Error

```
 df['col_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: convert_dates('col_1'), axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\103925alf1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6878, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Users\103925alf1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 186, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "C:\Users\103925alf1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 295, in apply_standard
    result = libreduction.compute_reduction(
  File "pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx", line 620, in pandas._libs.reduction.compute_reduction
  File "pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx", line 128, in pandas._libs.reduction.Reducer.get_result
  File "C:/Users/103925alf1/PycharmProjects/p09/p09.py", line 21, in <lambda>
    df['col_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: convert_dates('col_1'), axis=1)
  File "C:/Users/103925alf1/PycharmProjects/p09/p09.py", line 8, in convert_dates
    timestamp2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp_str[7:20])/1000)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to add the row(`x`) that it's being modified:

```
def convert_dates(timestamp_str):
    timestamp2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp_str[7:20])/1000)
    timestamp3 = timestamp2.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    return timestamp3

df['col_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: convert_dates(x['col_1']), axis=1)
```

Also, you could try to use the function of pandas `pd.to_datetime` instead of apply:

```
df['col_3']=pd.to_datetime(df['col_1'].str[7:20].astype('int64'),unit='ms').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

Both outputs:

```
df
   ID                    col_1                 col_3
0   1  \/Date(1529424891295)\/  2018-06-19T16:14:51Z
1   2  \/Date(1529424891295)\/  2018-06-19T16:14:51Z
2   3  \/Date(1529424891295)\/  2018-06-19T16:14:51Z
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you found the answer helpful, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) and upvote it :) @AleksandrsFrolovs